# verifyTrue(false) is not failing the testcase

Tags: junit, selenium

As per the documents, “assert” will fail the test and abort the current running test case, whereas a “verify” will fail the test and continue to run the test case.
But   verifyTrue(false) is not failing the case(rather continue with the next step and mark the case as passed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that's a Selenium call, then according to [this](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/SeleneseTestCase.html), "[verify methods] don't stop the test when they fail. Instead, verification errors are all thrown at once during tearDown."

Comment: How can I get the fail result during using verifyTrue()? Assume my test is failed: as test is continuing and it shows pass I am not getting the fail result after execution